# Sources for AWS associate developer certification

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am planning to get **AWS associate developer certified**.So few questions I have regarding same:

1. Books I shall refer.
2. I am finding a lot of people recommending **acloudguru.com** for it. Is it really worth it buying course from acloudguru and prepare from there.
3. What shall be my step by step process for clearing this exam and learning developing with AWS considering I am a newbie to AWS and cloud as well.
4. Any prerequisite before starting learning AWS.

Comment: I can heartily recommend the aCloudGuru courses. I passed SA and SysOps Associate Exams with them. You can even get those courses cheaper if you get them on udemy and then request the ACG guys to migrate your course to their platform (it's better than udemy's)

Comment: A cloud Guru has not update their developer course on Udemy. And now AWS is asking much harder questions in Developer asssociate exam.

Answer (score 8):

I have the AWS SA Pro and DevOps Pro. I volunteer teach the AWS SA Associate to teenagers on Saturdays.

1. Get as much hands on experience with AWS as you can. There is no replacement for being able to manage the core AWS services by heart.
2. Get the book AWS Certified Solutions Architect Official Study Guide. Very good book. Read from cover to cover two or three times. Practice every service in this book over and over.
3. A Cloud Guru and Linux Academy have very good courses. I have watched all of the A Cloud Guru classes, and most of the Linux Academy classes.
4. Watch all the AWS Deep Dive video on YouTube.
5. Read all the AWS White Papers. A lot of the exam questions come from the white papers.
6. Purchase the practice tests on https://www.whizlabs.com/. The SysOps exam is harder than the Developer or SA Associate. Try to get to the SysOps level before you take the Developer or SA.
7. Signup with Qwiklabs https://qwiklabs.com/. Very good guided labs for learning.

Note: I recommend taking both the Developer and the SA Associate at the same time. The exams are very similar.

**[Update Dec-04-2018]** I no longer recommend taking the Developer and SA at the same time. AWS has really improved the Developer exam and now the Developer exam is much harder and more focussed on developer tools. I took the new developer exam and I was impressed with the improvements and increased level of difficulty. [End Update].

Comment: Thank you John. How many weeks it can take to prepare for the same if I am willing to put in somewhere around 17-18 hours of practice per week? I'll be scheduling my exam accordingly.

Comment: This really depends on your experience level. If you are an IT beginner, I would guess six months to a year. Experienced IT person with one or more years with AWS, maybe six weeks. I would not worry about scheduling your exam at this point. Read a couple AWS white papers. This will help you get a feeling for where you are at. Start reading the AWS questions here on Stack Overflow. Once you start to know the answers and why your answer is the correct one, then consider taking the exam.